# Firestore Emulator and Wiremock in Integration Tests within Github Actions Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, github-actions, cicd, wiremock

i am building a Backend App in Nodejs. I mock my Database and API with Firestore and Wiremock.

Therefore, i am trying to check for my Integration Tests in my Github Actions Pipeline.

i have tried so far:

1. Running the firestore emulator over docker-compose.

This is not the recommended way, but the connection was somehow there in the pipeline.

This is my docker-compose file which the pipeline executed

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  firestore-emulator:
    image: mtlynch/firestore-emulator
    environment:
      - FIRESTORE_PROJECT_ID=test-project
      - FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=firestore-emulator:8888
      - PORT=8888
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/__test__/firestore-data:/opt/data

  wiremock:
    image: wiremock/wiremock:3.1.0
    container_name: wiremock-container
    command: --verbose
    ports:
      - "1080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/__test__/wiremock:/home/wiremock
  application:
    image: europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/woopick-registry/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: test
      SERVICE_PORT: 5000
      WOO_BASE_URL: http://wiremock:8080
      JWT_SECRET: secret
      FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST: firestore-emulator:8888
      FIRESTORE_PROJECT_ID: test-project
      PROJECT_ID: test-project

    depends_on:
      firestore-emulator:
        condition: service_started
      wiremock:
        condition: service_started
```

my pipeline:

```
      - name: Start wiremock and application
        run: |-
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.github-pipeline.yml up -d

      - name: Check Docker Network
        run: docker network ls

      - name: Check Wiremock Mount
        run: docker exec wiremock-container ls -al /home/wiremock/mappings

      - name: Run all the tests
        run: npm run test
```

This is where my test executed. Somehow, at *console.log*, the correct User is being printed out. But if i call the integration test with httpClient, there was no user found.

```
describe("Get products test", () => {

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await insertUser(mockUserWithHashedPassword);
    await mambuApiMockServer.requests.deleteAllRequests();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await clearFirestoreData({ projectId: "test-project" });
    await Promise.all(apps().map((app) => app.delete()));
  });

  it("should return a product list", async () => {
    const users = await getCollectionDocuments("users");
    console.log(users);
    const response = await httpClient.get("api/v1/products?per_page=10&page=1", { headers: { authorization: createAuthorizationHeader(mockUserWithHashedPassword.user_id) } });
    console.log(response.data);
```

```
application_1         | Running on 5000
application_1         | getUsers []
application_1         | warn: GET /products?per_page=10&page=1 - 404 - Not Found ***ERROR*** user not found by id 1
application_1         | info: GET /products?per_page=10&page=1 - 404
```

At this setup, the firestore emulator can not persist data after being inserted. but the connection was there, i guess?

2. Setting up firestore integration tests over sdk

This is what firebase official docs recommended:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  wiremock:
    image: wiremock/wiremock:3.1.0
    container_name: wiremock-container
    command: --verbose
    ports:
      - "1080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/__test__/wiremock:/home/wiremock
  application:
    image: europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/woopick-registry/$IMAGE_NAME:latest
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: test
      SERVICE_PORT: 5000
      WOO_BASE_URL: http://wiremock:8080
      FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST: host.docker.internal:8888
      JWT_SECRET: secret
      PROJECT_ID: test-project

    depends_on:
      wiremock:
        condition: service_started
```

This works fine locally when i set the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST to host.docker.internal:8888.But in the pipeline it doesnt connect.In order to run the emulator and test in debug modefirebase, this command is required:

```
firebase emulators:exec --project=test-project --only firestore 'npm run test'
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. I was trying on my own since weeks. repo: https://github.com/Woo-Pick-Fullfillment-Inventory/Backend-Woo-Inventory

thank you so much in advance!!!!